# Logical operations in Bash do not work as expected when matching a pattern

Tags: linux, bash, github, ubuntu-18.04, logical-operators

Could you please tell me what's wrong with this script?

```
if [[ " ${all[*]} " =~ " gcc " && \
      " ${all[*]} " =~ " release " && \
      false ]]
then
  additional_opts="gpu-compute-sanitizers"
else
  additional_opts=
fi
```

`false` comes from GitHub extensions while the actual script in the `.yaml` file is:

```
if [[ " ${all[*]} " =~ " gcc " && \
      " ${all[*]} " =~ " release " && \
      ${{contains(github.event.pull_request.body, '[GPU Compute Sanitizers]')}} ]]
then
  additional_opts="gpu-compute-sanitizers"
else
  additional_opts=
fi
```

The problem with this script is that the first branch is taken (`additional_opts="gpu-compute-sanitizers"`), while the pull request body doesn't contain the keyword.

`all` is an array of options like `gcc` and `release` or something else (`clang`, `debug`, etc).

The OS running the GitHub actions service is Ubuntu 18.04 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in the context of a bash conditional expression, `false` is true. Or rather, bash doesn't assign any special meaning to the string "false", it's just treated like any other string. In a conditional expression, a plain string is treated as though it had was the target of a `-n` ("is this string nonblank") operator, and since "false" is indeed nonblank the result comes out as true.

From the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> -n *string*
> *string*
> True if the length of *string* is non-zero.

Here's a quick demo:

```
$ [[ true ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ false ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ wibble ]] && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ [[ "" ]] && echo yes || echo no
no
```

Simple solution: test to see whether the result is the string "true":

```
if [[ " ${all[*]} " =~ " gcc " && \
      " ${all[*]} " =~ " release " && \
      ${{contains(github.event.pull_request.body, '[GPU Compute Sanitizers]')}} = true ]]
then
```

(Note: I'm assuming that expression will evaluate to either "true" or "false"; if it might evaluate to something else, you may have to use a more complicated test.)

Comment: Why doesn't Bash run commands `true` and `false` here that return the corresponding status?

Comment: @SergeRogatch To have them treated as commands, they have to occur in a command context; what's inside `[[ ]]` is treated as conditional expressions, not commands. Shell syntax is extremely context-dependent, and this is no exception. You could put the expression *outside* the `[[ ]]` so it'll be treated as a command: `if [[ " ${all[*]} " =~ " gcc " && " ${all[*]} " =~ " release " ]] && ${{contains(github.event.pull_request.body, '[GPU Compute Sanitizers]')}}; then`, but if it ever returns something other than "true" or "false", things might get weird.